# Freeform Checkbox Group Field only returns one value

Tags: plugin-freeform, checkboxes

I need a scenario where users can select multiple options within a checkbox group.  Unfortunately Freeform only returns the last value selected and ignores the rest?  I might be missing the point but I expected to see all (and only) the values selected represented in the submissions area?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Solspace support cam through via email with the answer...  Put square brackets after the field name!  Simple :)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="MyFieldName[]" value="Item1">
<input type="checkbox" name="MyFieldName[]" value="Item2">
<input type="checkbox" name="MyFieldName[]" value="Item3">
```