# Problem with truncated Freeform checkbox group value when mapped to another field

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace, array

NB: this is *not* the same as [Freeform Checkbox Group Field only returns one value](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/31438/freeform-checkbox-group-field-only-returns-one-value), which was resolved by field name markup invoking an array: `name="fieldname[]"`.

I'm already doing that. And stored Freeform form submissions are respecting multiple values.

My issue is that I am using **Element Connections** to map the form fields to other fields in the system which are assigned to user accounts.

The receiving fields are multiline Plain Text fields and they are only receiving a single value.

For example:

For a Freeform checkbox group…

```
<input name="group[0] type="checkbox" value="val1">
<input name="group[1] type="checkbox" value="val2">
<input name="group[2] type="checkbox" value="val3">
```

…that maps to user account field `userData2`.

When all three checkboxes are checked:

- the Freeform `group` field stores a value of `val1, val2, val3`
- but `userData2` only receives `val1`.

Comment: Thanks for improving the tags, Brad :)

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the [Element Connections](https://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v3/overview/element-connections.html) feature requires that a Freeform array field be mapped to a Craft field that also accepts an array (e.g. Freeform Checkbox Group to Craft Checkboxes).

I've made a note about this for us to revisit in the future though, and potentially add a transformer to handle this kind of mapping. :)

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. And now that I do I can manage the mapping in future with a more appropriate field.